# Inserting a row in a Word table from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains information to be put into a Word invoice template. I am able to populate header details, such as client name, address, etc.

I need to add the number of invoice lines so that I can populate the body of the invoice.

```vb
Dim wdApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
wdApp.Visible = True
On Error GoTo 0
wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(invoiceTemplate)
invoiceRowsToAdd = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(tblRegister.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), client) - 1
If invoiceRowsToAdd > 0 Then
    wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(3, 1).Range.Rows.Select
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow invoiceRowsToAdd
End If
```

If I check the Word document, the row is being selected, however it doesn't add any rows.
I confirmed that the `invoiceRowsToAdd` variable is returning the correct value.

Comment: Try avoid using `.Select`: `wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(3, 1).Range.Rows.InsertRowsBelow invoiceRowsToAdd`? Make sure the correct document is the `ActiveDocument` too.

Comment: If your template was designed to have the output table in the desired location, with just the header row and an empty data row, you could simply copy the excel range and paste it into Word using .PasteAppendTable, after which you could delete the empty data row. The use of an empty data row presupposes the table header row is formatted differently from the data rows.

Comment: @BruceWayne unfortunately still the same result with no rows being added below the selected row.  If I use
`For i = 1 To invoiceRowsToAdd
   wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Add
  Next i`
then I get the correct number of rows added below the table, but this isn't what I need.  Below the invoice detail lines I have the totals so the blank rows are in the wrong spot

Comment: @macropod, at the bottom of the table I have the invoice totals, tax, etc which are different to the details lines

Comment: «at the bottom of the table I have the invoice totals, tax, etc» So add those rows & details after doing the paste. Hardly rocket science. You'd have to do that much anyway.